# Cannot use CSV GUI Import to api Fatal error

Tags: import

WP 5.7.8 civi 5.59.4 CSV GUI Import to api 1.12
Have cleared cache and emptied templates_c
Have uninstalled and reinstalled but get error below when I try to use ie it doesnt start just get the below [image]

Nothing in config&log file
php log =

```
2023/05/17 05:33:28 [error] 101837#101837: *972345 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _civicrm_api3_form_processor_default_data_action_create_spec() (previously declared in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.form-processor/api/v3/FormProcessorDefaultDataAction/Create.php:13) in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.form-processor/api/v3/FormProcessorValidateAction/Create.php on line 13" while reading response header from upstream, client: 125.168.64.134, server: *****.org.au, request: "GET /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcsvimporter%2Fimport HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php8.0-fpm-*****.sock:", host: "*****.org.au:46442", referrer: "https://*****.org.au/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2FupdateConfigBackend&reset=1"
2023/05/17 05:30:59 [error] 101837#101837: *972118 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "group_by" in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_AU/%%F5/F54/F5478576%%Table.tpl.php on line 190PHP message: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "group_by" in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_AU/%%F5/F54/F5478576%%Table.tpl.php on line 193PHP message: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "group_by" in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_AU/%%F5/F54/F5478576%%Table.tpl.php on line 190PHP message: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "group_by" in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_AU/%%F5/F54/F5478576%%Table.tpl.php on line 193PHP message: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "group_by" in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_AU/%%F5/F54/F5478576%%Table.tpl.php on line 190PHP message: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "group_by" in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_AU/%%F5/F54/F5478576%%Table.tpl.php on line 193PHP message: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "group_by" in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_AU/%%F5/F54/F5478576%%Table.tpl.php on line 190PHP message: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "group_by" in /www/*****_235/public/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_AU/%%F5/F54/F5478576%%Table.tpl.php on line 193" while reading response header from upstream, client: 125.168.64.134, server: *****.org.au, request: "GET /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Finstance%2F129&reset=1&section=2&context=dashlet&snippet=json&crmAngularModules=api4,crmDashboard,crmResource,crmUi,crmUtil,dialogService,ui.sortable HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php8.0-fpm-*****.sock:", host: "*****.org.au:46442", referrer: "https://*****.org.au/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcsvimporter%2Fimport"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line is showing a fatal error arising from the Form Processor code.  Check that you have the latest version of that, or try disabling it.